# How to modify the woodplanks size ?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

There is possible to modify the size of the woodplanks ? I created a 10x10 meter room and not realistic in this size. With mapping I got weak result. Make the full floor from smaller parts it is not so elegant.

[image]

(Sorry for silly question, I'm a ~6 hour blender user and yeah, I skipped the basics.)

Thank you for your help!

David

Answer (score 1):

You could try by changing the scale

[image]

Good Luck